# Cherry picks from gerrit overwritten by repo sync

Tags: android, git, repository, cherry-pick

Basically the title is my problem. I'm building Cyanogenmod while picking a few different things from their gerrit. I would like to save them permanently with my local source. I thought that `git add .` or `git add -A` would do the trick, but all my picks seem to be overwritten anytime I sync up.

I've failed at googling the answer as I'm just coming up with the same things telling me what I'm doing is correct.

Any help here?

Comment: So your problem is when you do repo sync it is creating merge commit with your local unmerged changes??